# Windows 7 - Always select the "bigger" file when merging directories?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, merge

Is it possible to only merge/move/copy the larger file when merging two directories of the same name in Windows 7?

[image: confirmation dialog]

My specific scenario is merging two music libraries from old machines onto a new one. THe old libraries may have been ripped at a lower bitrate, and so I *always* want the larger of the two files to be kept when given a choice.

Right now, I'm stuck pressing "No" on every one

Comment: Are the lower bit rate files always older? If the two machines you're moving them from are 'old' machines. If so you could write a script that does not overwrite newer files (by datestamp) with older ones for example using Xcopy with the /D switch set

Comment: @Joe Taylor - not alwaysold: but they are *always* smaller!

Comment: You are gonna have to batch file this one buddy.

Comment: @surfasb - could you suggest a batch file way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If not a batchfile, tryin [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/).

> 2.3.3  by File Size
>
> You may use the relative file size as the file
>   selection criteria.  The switches listed below are
>   mutually exclusive.
>
> /BZ   Same as /BZX
>   /BZE  Backs up equal-size  files  (includes brand new files).
>   /BZL  Backs up larger-size files  (includes brand new files).
>   /BZS  Backs up smaller-size files (includes brand new files).
>   /BZX  Backs up different-size files  (includes brand new files).

Comment: what would the batch/powershell route look like?